# GridView with multiselect

Tags: gridview, qml, qt5, qt-quick

I need a `GridView` with multiselection. I couldn't find any exisitng solution so I decided to extend `GridView`'s functionality.

I wrote a fast draft for handling multiselection:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import cpp_objects.qml 1.0


GridView {
    id: grid

    function isSelected(index) {
        return selectionManager.isIndexSelected(index)
    }

    SelectionManager {
        id: selectionManager
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        propagateComposedEvents: true

        onClicked: {
            var ctrl = mouse.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier;

            if (ctrl == false)
                selectionManager.clearSelection()

            var index = grid.indexAt(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            selectionManager.toggleIndexSelection(index)

            mouse.accepted = false
        }
    }
}
```

`SelectionManager` is implemented on cpp side and collects selected items.

Here is its interface:

```
class SelectionManagerComponent: public QObject
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        SelectionManagerComponent(QObject * = nullptr);

        Q_INVOKABLE void toggleIndexSelection(int);
        Q_INVOKABLE void clearSelection();
        Q_INVOKABLE bool isIndexSelected(int) const;

    private:
        std::unordered_set<int> m_selected;
};
```

And now I have faced the most challanging issue: how can I visualize my extra selection?
I would like this qml component to be as generic as possible so I'd prefer not to provide hardcoded delegate here. Perfect solution would be to add some kind of 'selectionDelegate' property which would take an `Item` and would work same way as `delegate` and `highlight` do, so I can inherite from my custom `GridView` and define how do mark selected items. But that doesn't seem to be doable.

Are there any other possibilities or options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do it.

1. Use a `Loader` as your delegate. Change the `sourceComponent` depending on if your item is selected or not.

```
GridView {

    // Define these to specify your selected/unselected delegates
    property Component selectedComponent
    property Component unselectedComponent

    delegate: Loader {
        sourceComponent: selectionManager.isIndexSelected(index)
                             ? selectedComponent 
                             : unselectedComponent
    }
}
```

2. Or you can use a [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html). It allows you to use different delegates depending on the value of one of the fields in your model. I would have made this the first choice, but I don't know if it will work with your selectionManager since that's not related to the model data. But maybe there's still a way to get it to work.

```
GridView {

    // Define these to specify your selected/unselected delegates
    property Component selectedComponent
    property Component unselectedComponent

    delegate: DelegateChooser {
        role: "selected"  // <-- This needs to be a role in your model
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: true; selectedComponent }
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: false; unselectedComponent }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is useful however my main issue is that I'd like prepare a reusable `GridView` component which can be used without knowing much about insides and my idea was to extend `GridView`'s interface with a new property with an `Item` which would be used to draw selection. So my custom `GridView` would have to inject provided item into delegate painting process.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't explicit about that, but let me make that more clear in an edit.